# How do I set ProducesResponseType for all controllers in my app?

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I have middleware that handles all unhandled exceptions and returns

```
public class ErrorResponseModel { 
  public string ErrorMessage { get; set; } 
}
```

I like to add `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponseModel), 500)]` to all my controllers, but I don't understand how to do it once (w/o duplicating or introducing base class for all my controllers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add it as a global filter like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(o =>
    {
        o.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(typeof(ErrorResponseModel), 500));
    })
}
```

This is essentially the same as applying to all controllers.